# What is the difference between Html::encode() and just the basic html code in YII2?

Tags: yii2

I'm a beginner in YII and I don't know whats the difference between `<?= Html::encode($this->title)?>` to just `<?= $this->title?>`.. I have tested these two and they seemed to give the same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docs and source code can tell you everything.

Basically `Html::encode()` is just the wrapper of `htmlspecialchars` native PHP function:

> Encodes special characters into HTML entities.
>
> The application charset will be used for encoding.

To understand the basic difference and benefit of that, try to echo:

```
$string = '<script>alert(1);</script>';

echo $string;
```

and then:

```
echo Html::encode($string);
```

So `encode` is useful for filtering user saved data. If the data comes from developer, not from user, you may not apply `encode` and HTML will be displayed as is.

**Official docs:**

- [Html::encode()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#encode%28%29-detail)
- [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)